# Problema con el {{ url()->previous() }}

Tags: laravel

Estoy tratando de hacer un botón "Volver" eficiente si el envío fue un éxito.

En el formulario `create.blade.php` tengo un botón "Volver" como este:

```
<a href={{ url()->previous() }}>
    <button type="button">Volver</button>
</a>
```

Puedes ir a `create.blade.php` desde `previous_url_1.blade.php` o `previous_url_2.blade.php` ya que ambos tienen links a `create.blade.php`.

Una vez estas en `create.blade.php` y quieres volver, pulsas el botón y el `{{ url()->previous() }}` funciona perfectamente con ambos ejemplos.

**¿Pero que pasa si fallas el `$request_validation` dandole al submit en el form?**

La web se refresca automaticamente mostrando los errores de validación y el `{{ url()->previous() }}` cambia de `http://x.test:8080/previous_url_x` a `http://x.test:8080/article/create`.

¿Hay alguna forma de mantener el primer `{{ url()->previous() }}` independientemente de cuántas veces se actualice la página, independientemente del motivo de la actualización?

¿O tal vez puedas pensar en otra solución mejor? ¿Cómo bloquear el envío si no se cumplen las reglas de validación? ¿Es eso posible?

**Edito**

Ya he encontrado la respuesta, pero debido a que Stack Overflow es una comunidad sumamente tóxica cuyos moderadores son, literalmente, ego simps con unos aires de grandeza desmedidos, pero que en la vida real te agachan la mirada como buenos incels, no pienso poner la respuesta.

Y si, era un pedazo de código bien dificil de sacar, y bastante provechoso, pero mira, Stack Overflow no va a tenerla por sus maneras de tratar a la gente.

Venga, ahí os quedais, volved a banear a un novato por no saber "redactar un mensaje", elitistas de un basurero ;)

Comment: Si lo que quieres es ir a una vista en concreto puedes utilizar el método `route('nombre de ruta')`, siempre que tengas una ruta que retorne dicha vista

Comment: No es eso lo que busco, lee el post principal, gracias.

Comment: Siento que no te haya sido de ayuda en su momento. Había entendido mal la pregunta, y siento que tu experiencia haya sido mala. Un saludo :)